# Embed Python in plugin-based multithreaded C++ app with no main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython

I'm curious if there is a hack to allow multiple independent Python interpreters inside one process. I know there are sub-interpreters, but these require a general director who is creating and assigning the sub-interpreters from the global one.

My scenario is creating a plugin that can be run inside a multi-threaded plugin runner, without knowing anything about the other plugins that are running, and without any support from the plugin runner (that is a technical limitation of the framework I work with).

So is there a way to encapsulate the Python interpreter and its globals in such a way that multiple plugins could call Py_Initialize/Py_Finalize without influencing each other?

Comment: Re, "multi-threaded plugin runner" Sounds scary. Threads are supposed to cooperate with each other. Even if they just ignore each other, threads _must_ be well behaved. If not, one rogue thread can take down the whole process. Running plug-ins as separate processes is much more safe.

Comment: Sometimes you have to sacrifice safety for speed...

Comment: Agreed, but I'll leave my comment for benefit of newer readers who haven't been there before. Sorry I can't help answer your question. I've embedded Java in an application, but never Python.